# Determine Min Max

Tags: javascript

Past 10 it will make the minimum the 10 and say the 6 the maximum aside from the number "1". I'm not sure why and if someone can let me know or push me towards the answer that would be great.

[image]
[image]

```
function btnMinMax_onclick()
{
    // assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
    var firstTextbox = document.getElementById("txtNum1");
    var secondTextbox = document.getElementById("txtNum2");
    var minTextbox = document.getElementById("txtMin");
    var maxTextbox = document.getElementById("txtMax");

    var num1 = firstTextbox.value;
    var num2 = secondTextbox.value;

    var isMin = determineMinimum(num1, num2); 
    var isMax = determineMaximum(num1, num2); 

    minTextbox.value = isMin;
    maxTextbox.value = isMax;
}

function determineMinimum(number1, number2)
{
    if (number1 < number2){
        return number1;
    } else {
        return number2;
    }
}

function determineMaximum(number1, number2)
{
    if (number2 > number1){
        return number2;
    } else {
        return number1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `Math.min` and `Math.max` are perfect for this ... also, you want to parseFloat the `.value` to convert it from a string to a Number so you compare Numbers not lexically

Comment: @JaromandaX I need to use determineMaximum and determineMinimum functions

Comment: right ... so, still parseFloat the value "Strings" first so you're comparing numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you're pulling from the text boxes are `String`, not `Number`. You need to convert explicitly or it will order lexicographically, not numerically.

Simplest solution is to change:

```
var num1 = firstTextbox.value;
var num2 = secondTextbox.value;
```

to:

```
var num1 = parseInt(firstTextbox.value, 10);
var num2 = parseInt(secondTextbox.value, 10);
```

so you have real integer values, not strings that look like integers. Use `parseFloat` instead if you need to accept non-integer values (e.g. `3.14`).

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a problem here:

```
var num1 = firstTextbox.value;
var num2 = secondTextbox.value;

var isMin = determineMinimum(num1, num2); 
var isMax = determineMaximum(num1, num2);
```

The `.value` will get you a `string`. But you want to compare numbers, so you have to convert the string to a number before comparing it.

You could do it like this:

```
function determineMinimum(number1, number2) {
    number1 = Number(number1);
    number2 = Number(number2);

    // your code here
}
```

Comment: A variable which the name starts with `is` always returns a boolean value.

Comment: @TânNguyễn: It _should_, but there is no language feature that forces it. You can't say it _always_ stores a boolean. The OP used the name, I'm not going to knock an answer for reusing it.